# Customize jQuery submenu positioning

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu, menu

I am trying to create a horizontal menu that has at least two levels of submenus.  All submenus are vertical.

Submenu1 will be directly below its parent.
All subsequent submenu levels (2+) should be to the right of its parent.

I am just starting to learn how to use jQuery menu, and they don't seem to have a customization for this.  I am not sure how to approach this... I tried and failed to call `.menu()` on `$("#myMenu .level1")`.

My question is - I would much appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction on how to make the menu as I have stated above.

Javascript snippet

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#myMenu").menu({
      position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom"
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML snippet

```
<ui id="myMenu">
  <li class="level1">
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="level2">
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="level3">
            <a href="#">Item 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Update: [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/uxuTAba/1/)

Comment: can you upload some live code? It can be fixed with CSS

Comment: @Danko updated with JSbin, not sure why there's a funky white bar in the example but it looks fine on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi finally i have an answer for your question. Using some properties of the menu like blur and focus. I found this page that already has the solution http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-make-the-perfect-horizontal-menu. I studied those lines and applied it in your code. If you have any question about the functionality feel free to ask.

Review the new code here http://jsbin.com/uxuTAba/5/.

Comment: wow, I didn't think there was a simple solution such as this.  Thank you!  I hunted around the internet, and found a diff solution using TinyDropDown as well.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedocode:

```
On mouseover of Menu Item, slidedown List (positioned right under Menu Item)
On mouseover of List Element, slidedown List Element X's Submenu (positioned to the right of X)
```

Basically what I am saying is, to position your menus with CSS and then use slideDown() and slideUp() to display them dynamically. So the menus positioning does not need to be determined with the jQuery at all -- just the display status of sliding them up/down. But they're all positioned relative to the menu, with your base CSS.