# Menu bar using Jquery 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, menu

I simply want the first menu sub items to appear below the top menu item and then all subsequent menu sub items to behave as the default behavior for JQuery menu.  I have it working somewhat with fading in and out on the first sub menu item but as soon as I click the top menu, it reverts back to JQuery default from JQuery UI.

Is there a way to change or stop this default behavior?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/indianapolymath/rV7mX/2/

```
$("#EnvironmentalMenu").menu();
$(".firstSubNav").position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "center bottom",
    collision: "fit"
});

$(function () {
    $('.nav li').hover(
        function () { 
            $('ul', this).fadeIn();
        },
        function () { 
            $('ul', this).fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

I have tried .position but doesn't seem to help but I have never used position and may not be using it correctly. Just so I do not get responses for other widgets, I want to use JQuery menu to implement this so I can take advantage of the CSS UI theme.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position

Comment: Check this question maybe the answer is waht you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432971/customize-jquery-submenu-positioning/19459259#19459259

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change is:

```
$("#EnvironmentalMenu").menu();
var position = $(".firstSubNav").position({
    my: "left top",
    at: "center bottom",
    collision: "fit"
});
$("#EnvironmentalMenu").menu( "option", "position");
```

You initialized the menu and its position but you never *set* it

Found it from [searching the jQuery UI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/#option-position)

Comment: I should have said that position probably is not an option to fix the original question "Is there a way to change or stop this default behavior?".  Made the change, same behavior.  Please see the fiddle.

Comment: it might be hard and redundant to try and do it with jQuery UI. Creating your own with just JavaScript and CSS may give you what you want. Might take longer but the end result will be more fulfilling.